# Adicionar ou habilitar itens no Pallet no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Por favor, sabem como habilito o Person Name, TextView Large, Textview Medium, Textview Small no Pallet do Android Studio? Eles não aparecem aqui.

Grato

[image: pallete faltando itens]

Comment: Aparece como aí?

Comment: como Na figura não aparecem TextView Large, TextView Small no Text Fields

Comment: e no widget nã oaparece Person Name